# It seems a simple question to prove $-1\leq ax+by \leq 1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Suppose $x^2+y^2=1$ and also $a^2+b^2=1$. Prove that $$-1\leq  ax+by \leq 1$$ for all $a,b,x,y$ .

It seems a simple question ,but I get stuck on this ...pleas give me hint . Thanks in advance.

It is obvious that $$|a|\leq 1 ,also \space for \space b,y,x $$so easy to say $$|ax+by|\leq 1+1$$ but for $|ax+by|\leq 1 $ what we can do  ?

Comment: May help to think of it as "*the dot product of two unit vectors has an absolute value no larger than $1$*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another basic approach. Let 2-D points $(a,b)$ and $(x,y)$ corresponds to points $(\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta))$ and $(\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi))$ respectively in the unit-radius circle. Then convince yourself that $ax+by=sin(\theta+\phi)$ which gives you the result you want.

Comment: +! for nice idea

Answer (score 2):

By C-S 
$$1=(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)\geq(ax+by)^2,$$
which gives
$$-1\leq ax+by\leq1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Scalar Product:

1)$ \vec r :=(x,y)$ , $||(x,y)|| = 1$.

2) $\vec s := (a,b)$ , $||(a,b)|| = 1$.

$\vec r \cdot \vec s = ax +yb =$

$ ||\vec r||$ $ ||\vec s|| \cos(\phi) $.

$\Rightarrow$

$-1 \le ax +yb \le 1$, since

$ -1 \le cos(\phi) \le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant of the usual proof. The complex numbers $a+ib$ and $y+ix$ are each of modulus $1$ and hence their product is also of modulus $1$. It follows that the imaginary part of the product ie $ax+by$ is also less than $1$ in absolute value.